# Hint on how to create & pass data via segue when collectionview cell is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` embedded in a `UITableViewCell` & I want to perform a segue when a `UICollectionViewCell` is pressed & pass the data represented by that cell to the destination `ViewController` for detailed information.

Here is the code for the embedded `UICollectionView` inside the `UITableViewCell`

```
 @IBOutlet weak var EventCollection: UICollectionView!

  var events = [Events]()

 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
 EventCollection.delegate = self
 EventCollection.dataSource = self
 }

 extension PopularCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return events.count
   }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = EventCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "EventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventCell
            let event = events[indexPath.row]
            print("Event Name:\(event.event_name)")
             cell.event = event
         cell.tag = indexPath.row
            return cell

    }
```

How do I perform & prepare a segue in the main `ViewController` when a `UICollectionViewCell` is pressed so as to pass the data contained by that cell to the destination `ViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps that you need to do.

1. As you said, your CollectionView is inside `TableView`. So your TableView delegates/DataSources binded with the MainViewController. `CollectionView`  delegates/DataSources binded with the `TableViewCell`.
2. Now create a protocol to know user has clicked on `collectionView`.

   ```
   protocol MyProtocol : class {
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
   }
   ```
3. In `TableViewCell`, you need to call delegate like this,

   ```
   class MyTableCell : UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate {
       weak var delegate : MyProtocol?

       :
       :

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
           if let delegate = delegate {
               delegate.collectionView(collectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now your `MainViewController` must have to conform this protocol,

   ```
   class MainViewController :UIViewController, MyProtocol {
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
           // Do segue here ....
       }
   }
   ```

---

Note : Make sure to bind delegate with your `MainViewController` i.e. in `TableviewCellForRow` have `cell.delegate = self`

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the following code with in a new file named UIView_Ext

   ```
   extension UIView {
       var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
           var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
           while parentResponder != nil {
               parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
               if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                   return viewController
               }
           }
           return nil
       }
   }
   ```
2. In `func didSelectItem(At indexPath: IndexPath)` method , write the following code

   ```
   self.parentViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Identifer", sender: "Your Data in place of this string")
   ```

Comment: In what `func didSelectItem` should i put it ? TableViewCell ? or CollectionViewCell ?

Comment: In table view cell's didSelectItemAt indexPath method of collection view

Comment: Ie in the `UICollectionViewCell` ?

Comment: Not cell ..because your <didSelectItemAt IndexPath> method is implemented in table view cell . As you said your hierarchy is ViewController>TableView>TableViewCell>UICollectionView>UICollectionViewCell.  
So your table view didSelect Method might be in ViewController and Collection View DidSelect method in table view cell